# How to change the position of the heading?

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to figure out, how to change the position of the heading. I want the heading on the same sight as the page number of the document. See the photo attached:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\section{Abstract}
fngf
%\markboth{<left heading text>}{<right heading text>}
\subsection{Abstract}
fngf
\newpage
dgdfbhdthnfghnrfgfgtfrdfvjdnlsedvglneas
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `\ihead{\leftmark}` to `\ohead{\leftmark}` will keep the page numbers and heading aligned on the same side of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much!